# if i make a mistake in code and cause an infinite loop in javascript and it keeps on calling alert(), is there a way out to stop the loop?

Tags: javascript, firefox, alert

sometimes i use debug code to alert something in javascript (for example, matching something in regular expression), but forget a modifier and and the alert is in an infinite loop (or if the loop matches the pattern 300 times).  If using Firefox, the alert keeps on coming out, and there is no way to even close the tab, the window, or the app.

If I force exit, it will close all the tabs and even other windows of Firefox...  is there actually a way to stop the loop more gracefully?

Comment: Since you're not asking how to change your code, this really belongs on SuperUser. It's an accidental instance of the classic never-ending alert prank sites.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

This is one good reason to use Firebug and the console.log function. Which, ironically, will cause the "stop script because it's running away dialog" to not display in some cases, meaning you are right back where you are now.

Chrome and Opera have this feature. IE doesn't, Apple Safari doesn't either.

Not a native solution but you could try this grease-monkey script: http://www.tumuski.com/2008/05/javascript-alert-cancel-button/

Also, you *could* simply override the alert function to use a confirm dialog instead and stop showing alerts if the confirm is canceled:

```
var displayAlerts = true;
```

And then:

```
function alert(msg) {
  if (displayAlerts) {
     if (!confirm(msg)) {
       displayAlerts = false;           
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Opera has a "Stop executing scripts in this page" checkbox at the bottom of alert windows

Comment: This is no longer true, see Alex Key's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can in firefox:

1. Hold Ctrl
2. Hold Enter
3. Press F4 once

According to the blog post, it doesn't work in all cases, more information here: [puremango.co.uk](http://www.puremango.co.uk/2010/02/break-out-of-infinite-alert-popups/)

Comment: btw. I'd recommend using console.log, but if you have got yourself in an alert() loop (like I just have, it's a good escape).

Comment: Excellent - people should still use console ;), but that's more opinion, and in the spirit of this ancient question, I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: Totally agree @altCognito (+1); the console is in 99.99% of the time the best option. One situation I've found where an alert() is handy in some browsers is catching variables just before a window close in 3rd party code. e.g. When debugging 3rd party e-learning courseware which often initiates actions when the window is closed. Firebug will persist console output after a window close, but other browsers don't.

Comment: actually you dont need to use 'ENTER', just ctrl + f4 is enough.

Comment: Old question, old answer. But still save me from ending all open chrome tasks :) By the way, it only works in the described order, meaning, Enter is essential!

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome allows you to prevent additional alerts from showing.

Comment: You'd think this would have been an obvious feature for all browsers.

Comment: It always suprised me that browser didn't have this. Thank god chrome introduced it.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Firefox extension to combat this problem.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13176

Answer (score 0):

No way. Good thing is though most browsers have infinite recursion protection, but that's offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

Install Greasemonkey and go to this page:
http://www.tumuski.com/2008/05/javascript-alert-cancel-button/

After you install this script for greasemonkey, any alert dialog window will have a cancel button which it will stop the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

[tested on IE 11] If you need to close the web browser and don't want to ctrl-alt-del for whatever reason (in my case my bad javascript infinite alert loop was running on citrix which would automatically reload my last session after a ctrl-alt-del from the cache memory which I can't clear)

you can bug your way out by **holding down alt-F4 and spamming the X** (to close the browser window).

This works really fast... The alt-F4 closes the alert boxes really fast and you will notice the X button at the top of your browser flickering. This gives you very small windows of time where you can close it between alerts.

Note: if you have multiple tabs open you need to close them from the icon on the control bar at the bottom of your screen first because the "close all tabs message" will interfere.